# Need to generate output in the following format year, q1,q2,q3,q4 in the MS SQL server for below data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named acquisition (create table statement and insert statement is share here). I want to add another column to the select statement which will indicate the quarter with year ("2020 q1") for each row.

**Create table statement:**

```
CREATE TABLE acquisition (
   id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
   company_name VARCHAR(100),
   cost_amount INT NOT NULL,
   acquired_at DATE NOT NULL
);
```

**Insert statements:**

```
INSERT INTO acquisition(company_name, cost_amount, acquired_at)
VALUES
(1,'HOFA', 6850, '2010-01-17'),
(2,'POGA', 9256, '2019-09-04'),
(3,'CUPU', 9329, '2012-08-21'),
(4,'BULO', 5162, '2020-11-21'),
(5,'GICE', 5301, '2012-10-04'),
(6,'TOSE', 1790, '2018-09-30'),
(7,'POWU', 7183, '2019-05-21'),
(8,'YEJO', 1491, '2010-12-12'),
(9,'XAMO', 5974, '2010-03-23'),
(10,'TEFA', 9456, '2012-06-29'),
(11,'GOCU', 2469, '2018-04-04'),
(12,'VOLU', 5478, '2020-02-26'),
(13,'RISO', 1127, '2020-04-09'),
(14,'GATI', 8478, '2016-07-31'),
(15,'DIFA', 2655, '2019-06-12'),
(16,'VAYA', 7113, '2019-03-19'),
(17,'KIRE', 6997, '2019-02-17'),
(18,'MOMU', 9633, '2019-05-21'),
(19,'ROKU', 2790, '2019-10-30'),
(20,'KALI', 1969, '2020-07-06'),
(21,'FIKE', 8104, '2019-12-20'),
(22,'KULA', 2695, '2016-08-17'),
(23,'MILE', 5942, '2016-11-02'),
(24,'BITO', 9578, '2019-01-08');
```

**Sample output:**

```
| id  | company_name | cost_amount | acquired_at | Quarter |
| --- | ------------ | ----------- | ----------- | ------- |
| 1   | HOFA         | 6850        | 2010-01-17  | 2010 Q1 |
| 2   | POGA         | 9256        | 2019-09-04  | 2019 Q3 |
| 3   | CUPU         | 9329        | 2012-08-21  | 2012 Q3 |
| 4   | BULO         | 5162        | 2020-11-21  | 2020 Q4 |
| 5   | GICE         | 5301        | 2012-10-04  | 2012 Q4 |
```

Comment: can you share example of output format?

Comment: Please define "q1,q2", is that quarter (define quarter), do you want the sum total for the year as well as the quarter?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to add a column named quarter to show which calendar quarter it is then you can use datepart with quarter as below:

```
select* ,CONCAT(YEAR(acquired_at),' Q',datepart(quarter,acquired_at))Quarter from acquisition
```

**Output:**

| id | company_name | cost_amount | acquired_at | Quarter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HOFA | 6850 | 2010-01-17 | 2010 Q1 |
| 2 | POGA | 9256 | 2019-09-04 | 2019 Q3 |
| 3 | CUPU | 9329 | 2012-08-21 | 2012 Q3 |
| 4 | BULO | 5162 | 2020-11-21 | 2020 Q4 |
| 5 | GICE | 5301 | 2012-10-04 | 2012 Q4 |
| 6 | TOSE | 1790 | 2018-09-30 | 2018 Q3 |
| 7 | POWU | 7183 | 2019-05-21 | 2019 Q2 |
| 8 | YEJO | 1491 | 2010-12-12 | 2010 Q4 |
| 9 | XAMO | 5974 | 2010-03-23 | 2010 Q1 |
| 10 | TEFA | 9456 | 2012-06-29 | 2012 Q2 |
| 11 | GOCU | 2469 | 2018-04-04 | 2018 Q2 |
| 12 | VOLU | 5478 | 2020-02-26 | 2020 Q1 |
| 13 | RISO | 1127 | 2020-04-09 | 2020 Q2 |
| 14 | GATI | 8478 | 2016-07-31 | 2016 Q3 |
| 15 | DIFA | 2655 | 2019-06-12 | 2019 Q2 |
| 16 | VAYA | 7113 | 2019-03-19 | 2019 Q1 |
| 17 | KIRE | 6997 | 2019-02-17 | 2019 Q1 |
| 18 | MOMU | 9633 | 2019-05-21 | 2019 Q2 |
| 19 | ROKU | 2790 | 2019-10-30 | 2019 Q4 |
| 20 | KALI | 1969 | 2020-07-06 | 2020 Q3 |
| 21 | FIKE | 8104 | 2019-12-20 | 2019 Q4 |
| 22 | KULA | 2695 | 2016-08-17 | 2016 Q3 |
| 23 | MILE | 5942 | 2016-11-02 | 2016 Q4 |
| 24 | BITO | 9578 | 2019-01-08 | 2019 Q1 |

Comment: @karthik is it your desired output? Please let me know.

Comment: Learned a new thing of `quarter` keyword. :-)